# Disable doctrine cache for test environment / unittests (symfony 4)

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I have a unittests in my Symfony 4 project which show a inconsistent behaviour and I suspect the doctrine caching is responsible for this. So I am looking for a way to disable caching for Unittests.

My current packages/test/doctrine.yaml file for the environment test looks like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.result_cache_provider

services:
    doctrine.result_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

If I want to disable any caching in doctrine for tests, is there any cache driver, which is a non-caching dummy? If I leave  those entries empty I guess my prod settings or the general settings would be used, which means the results would also be cached. Can I explicitly non-cache? I hope I would not have to write an explicit dummy cache provider, who doesn't cache? This could be a solution, but it looks to me like this should be achieved more easily.

```
config
    \__packages
        |
        |__ prod
        |   \__doctrine.yaml
        |
        |__ dev
        |   \__doctrine.yaml
        |
        |__ test
        |   \__doctrine.yaml
        |
        \__doctrine.yaml
```

This is my extended KernelTestCase class:

```
protected EntityManagerInterface $em;

public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
{
    parent::setUpBeforeClass();

    $kernel = static::createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();
    $em = $kernel
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();
    $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
    $metadata = $em
        ->getMetadataFactory()
        ->getAllMetadata();

    // Drop and recreate tables for all entities
    $schemaTool->dropSchema($metadata);
    $schemaTool->createSchema($metadata);
}


protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    self::ensureKernelShutdown();

    $kernel = static::createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();

    $this->em = $kernel
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();

    // loads tests data for every tests
    $projectDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();
    system('php ' . $projectDir . '/bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test -n -q');
}

....

protected function tearDown(): void
{
    parent::tearDown();
    if (null !== $this->em) {
        $this->em->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using the `array` one - see: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-orm-configuration and https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

Comment: But also the array is still caching: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/cache/adapters/array_cache_adapter.html I will have to set at least a cache time out to 1 second, which is long, when you consider how fast unit tests can run.

Comment: First you should realize that if you are trying to unit test some class and you are touching Doctrine (or other services, things from Symfony container, database, external resources etc) then this is not unit test :) Unit test should test only one class and dependencies of such class should be mocked / stubbed. Can you paste your test here?

Comment: yes yes yes.....  however you call it. I want to test if my service properly saves data to the db after it did other shenannigans. If that would not be the case I would not care about db caching, eh? And if your test passes sometimes and other times not, caching is always a good suspect.

Comment: Ok. Please try to execute only 1 test (using `--filter=myTestMethodName` option of phpunit). Also try to inspect data in db using raw SQL queries ( https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql ). Query the data that you want to inspect at beginning of test, and also at end of test - and compare those 2 results. If you want to be 200% sure that you dont hit any cache then add something like `AND ' . rand(1,1000000)` to `WHERE` clause of that query. This way you should either spot problem caused by cache or exclude this possibility.

Comment: I already did that. If only the one test runs, even if only this one test class is running life is fine. Only if I run all tests and even then only sometimes I get this weird error.

Comment: adding the random is a nice idea, but I don't use a raw SQL  or PDO query  but this:  $charges = $this->chargeRepo->findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC'], 1, 0); And sometimes nothing is found although there should be at least two entries.

Comment: There's `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter` specially for tests. You might need to override the default `DoctrineProvider`, though.

Comment: @CalamityJane `but I don't use a raw SQL or PDO query ...` - ok, my suggestion about using raw query was to use it only inside your test (so you dont need to modify your core/business code).

Comment: `Only if I run all tests and even then only sometimes I get this weird error.` - this behaviour suggests that your tests are not run "in isolation". In other words: some data in your db is not properly cleaned up after each test and/or initialized before each test. See for example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test

Comment: @domis86  Interesting: With that packacge config I can set db caching to false?

Comment: @CalamityJane what you need is predictable (in simple cases: same) data before each test. Simplest way to achieve that is: before each test delete all data in db and load desired data into db - and then execute your test. This way is easy but slow (loading whole db data before each test is slow). Abovementioned package (`dama/doctrine-test-bundle`) achieves similar effect, but does it faster - it essentially wraps your test within a transaction - and rollbacks said transaction after - effectively "resetting" the data. This is much faster than simple delete&load technique.

Comment: @domis86 exactly that is what I am doing. For each test. I am just trying out the mentioned bundle, but I can only make the final test after some PRs of my software are approved & merged. I will come back with the result.

Comment: dama_doctrine_test:
    enable_static_connection: true
    enable_static_meta_data_cache: false
    enable_static_query_cache: false looks like I can set it to false with dama/doctrine-test-bundle however i still got my problem

Answer (score 2):

### cache configuration

> If I leave those entries empty I guess my prod settings or the general settings would be used

No, the settings from **prod will never ever be used in test** environment. Test uses the configuration from `config/packages/test/` and does fallback to the general settings in `config/packages/` but never to prod.

In a typical setup, general doctrine stuff like mappings are defined in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`, cache is only defined in `config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml`. See [official symfony demo application](https://github.com/symfony/demo/tree/master/config/packages)

You can also verify your configuration using `bin/console debug:config doctrine --env=test`.

### test isolation

Your problem is most probably not caused by doctrine cache configuration but by poor isolation of your testcases.

Have a look at [Functional Testing of A Doctrine Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#functional-testing-of-a-doctrine-repository). Symfonys official docs recommend to boot the kernel at `setUp()` and to close the entity manager during `tearDown()`.

If that complete isolation is not a feasible approach for you, you will have to debug to find out which testcase causes the breach of isolation. If you pinned the causing testcase you should check its execution path and look out for missing doctrine flushes and for transactions that are left open longer than expected.

Comment: You might be onto something here. I added the important function of my class, which extend the KernelTestCase in den question description. Any way a thumbs up for good  links and answer anyway.

Comment: So I do boot the Kernel with setUp and close it with tearDown, but still I get randomly crashing tests, which are totally fine for the next 3-6 runs ad then crash again. Or another test is suddenly crashing because something in the db cannot be found. I also checked for missing flushes after persits and they seem all to be there.

Comment: `but still I get randomly crashing tests, which are totally fine for the next 3-6 runs ad then crash again` - this may be also caused by some things in your code that rely either or "random number generation" (`if (rand(1,10) === 1) { boom(); }`) or "time related" things (`if ((new \DateTime())->format('s') % 5 === 0) { boom(); }`) - do you have something like this in your code? :)

Comment: With all the advice I improved the situation so that only in one of 6-8 runs a test is crashing. Bit still it happens.

Comment: Can you define what the "crash" means exactly? :) Test is failing? How is failing? Can you pinpoint which data in db has different value from what you expect (at the moment of failure)?

Comment: Good idea to check for the places, which might contain random values, but regrettably none of those places would cause it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the advice of everybody here it looks like I have finally fixed my problem. At least all tests are green in now 40 runs.

What I did:

Before I was manually loading my fixtures for each test and experimented with recreating the db for each testclass and then for each test.
I threw that away completely and now rely solely on the Dama Bundle and the transaction rollback to get unmodified test data.

```
dama_doctrine_test:
    enable_static_connection: true
    enable_static_meta_data_cache: false
    enable_static_query_cache: false
```

In the configuration of the Dama Bundle I did set the caches for the queries and meta data to false. I am not sure if this is necessary though. But since it didn't slow down my tests I keep it.

This combination finally did do the trick.

Thanks to @domis86 @simon.ro for your support and patience!

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing/database.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test
https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle